# Topology and Differential Geometry book (single one) for self-learning

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, differential-topology, self-learning, book-recommendation

After posting this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4521706/suggestion-of-around-6-books-in-the-topics-abstract-algebra-linear-algebra), I have decided to separate the contents into multiple questions.

Reasons I am doing this:

- Right tag for each topic, so people who are interested in that topic and watch that tag may suggest rather than one suggests books for all the mentioned topics. So it might be simpler and more efficient.
- Having difficulty to decide as everyone has his own opinion. But I believe there is something common for most of people who have read in this topic.
- I did not get many answers to see common suggestions and take a decision.
- So this post might be as voting post.

---

I need a book in:

$\big( \bigstar \big)$ Topology and Differential Geometry:

Some suggestions in this website are:

$\star$ *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds* by John Lee.

$\star$ *A First Course in Geometric Topology and Differential Geometry* by Ethan D. Bloch.

$\star$ *Elementary Topology and Applications* by Carlos R Borges.

---

Even though I have some knowledge in this topic, I want a book that is easy to read for self-learners, to be as comprehensive as possible (but starting from scratch, so it should not be 2nd text), contains proofs as much as possible, contains good number of examples/exercises, and requires least prerequisites.

---

Someone suggested

$\star$ *An Introduction to Manifolds* by Loring W. Tu.

But I am not sure if it satisfies the above criteria.

---

You can suggest other than the listed above if you think there is a better one, please suggest the best (one book containing both Topology and Differential Geometry) (in your opinion). Thanks a lot.

Comment: "Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces" Springer (Undergraduate Texts in Mathematics) 2016 
by Kristopher TAPP is a very accessible book for a first contact with original differential geometry by self learning. It is exceptionaly clear and well illustrated.

Comment: In the same vein, another very nicely illustrated book which isn't listed in the list of titles given in the reference of Hans Lundmark because it is more recent "A Visual Introduction to Differential Forms and Calculus on Manifolds" (Birkhaüser 2018) by Jon Pierre FORTNEY.